# How to create a mongo view providing data only for the latest as at date

Tags: mongodb, view, mongodb-query, query-optimization

In MSSQL the view can be easily created by running 2 queries:

- The first one gets the latest date available
- the second one extracts all records as at that date

How can I achieve the same results in Mongo? Mongo collection is Indexed by AsAtDate and Id.
Based on research, mongo only supports views created with a pipeline that doesn't support multiple queries.

Example:

```js
    db.getCollection('MyCollection').aggregate([
        {  "$lookup": 
            {
                "from": "CollectionAsAtDate",
                "pipeline": [
                    { "$sort": { "AsAtDate": -1 } },
                    { "$limit": 1 },
                    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "AsAtDate": 1 } }
                ],
                "as": "latest"
            } 
        },
        {"$unwind":"$latest"},
        { 
            "$match": {
                $expr: {
                    { $eq: [AsAtDate,"$latest.AsAtDate" ]}
                } 
            }
        }    
    ])
```

This piece of code is the best solution, I have found so far but it is still not efficient.
It takes me 10+ seconds to get data from a collection by already indexed parameters!

The reason for that is just because here we are trying to find *last date* and attach it to all documents. After that, we are checking if AsAtDate == LastAsAtDate and remove if not. It works okay but it requires more resources rather than a simple search in an index!

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the "sort-limit1" operation out from the sub-pipeline first? In this sense, you can ensure the index is leveraged and you are processing with only 1 document(i.e. the one with latest AsAtDate). You can avoid performing n-to-n `$lookup` with a 1-to-n `$lookup`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "AsAtDate": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "AsAtDate": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "AsAtDate",
      "foreignField": "AsAtDate",
      "as": "latest"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$latest"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$latest"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zqTxQiIKWxk) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you, ray! 

It looks like a great idea but I'm getting an error (in $lookup part): 
Mongo aggregation and MongoError: exception: BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 134217728 bytes, past the 64MB limit

Comment: @DenisEvseev The error is probably caused by the $lookup looked up too many documents. However, it should have been catered by [$lookup + $unwind coalesce](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-lookup----unwind-coalescence)... Can we have some of your sample data and the **exact** query you are running right now?

Comment: @DenisEvseev the error is suggesting you are making some mistakes when adopting my solution. Like in error 2, you are providing 'unwinding' as argument to `$lookup` which is incorrect. That is also why I am asking you to provide your exact query / current adoption so we can have a closer look.

Comment: [{
    $sort: {
        AsAtDate: -1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        AsAtDate: 1
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'HoldingsAsAtDate',
        localField: 'AsAtDate',
        foreignField: 'AsAtDate',
        as: 'latest'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$latest'
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: '$latest'
    }
}]

Comment: this is a query I am using, as you can see - the only difference is the collection name. 
I am using it to create Views. The query works superbly with a 100k number of records but fails on a collection with almost 3mln records

Comment: @DenisEvseev Would be grateful if you can try to set `allowDiskUse` option following [this doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/#index-use-and-sort-operations).

Comment: thank you, ray. I will try but we decided to review the collection to see if any records can be removed/archieved